# Jmeter isn't recording real device mobile app activity despite configuring everything carefully and repeatedly

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, http-proxy

Actually, I'm new in recording jmeter script from my real mobile device. So I followed a bunch of tutorials, and I configured everything as described. But when I started HTTP Test recorder of Jmeter and did some activity manually on my real device app, it's supposed to record the activities in jmeter. But nothing happens. I tried many solutions from online but it didn't work out.

I tried the following to configure mobile device and jmeter:

1. I created a HTTP Test Script Recorder in Jmeter, under HTTP test script recorder I added View results tree, added thread group, under thread group I added a recording controller.
2. I connected my pc and mobile device to the same wifi network. Note that my network is not real ip, it's shared ip.
3. I started HTTP Test Script Recorder and found the CA certificate in Jmeter directory, then I took the certificate in my mobile via email and installed the certificate
4. I configured my mobile wifi by selecting manual proxy, I put my pc ipv4 address in proxy hostname and put jmeter port in proxy port
5. Finally I started HTTP Test Script Recorder again and then opened an app in my mobile and did some activity

Expectation:

1. As I think I've configured everything correctly, the Jmeter was supposed to record my mobile activity. But it isn't recording anything.
2. After configuring manual proxy in my mobile with pc IPV4 address and jmeter port, the wifi of the mobile isn't getting internet access. But it should get internet access.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take at least one more action in order to get the traffic recorded:

- for iOS you need to [enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102390) for the JMeter's certificate
- for Android you need to [amend your application network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config) like it's described in [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) article

Also be informed that JMeter can only record HTTP or HTTPS traffic, if your application uses different/other [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) you will need to handle it differently, i.e. using a [network sniffer tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) for capturing the traffic and looking for Samplers or Plugins which support this protocol and manually building the requests.

Comment: JMeter isn't recording any apps of my phone. And also isn't it supposed to be able to access internet? The internet isn't also accessible. Actually I'm a bit confused with the solution you provided as I'm seeing everything here is associated with the specific app I'm testing. But it's not showing anything for any app.

Comment: If JMeter cannot access the Internet - "any apps" will not be able to access the Internet as well. If you're behind a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) you need to make JMeter aware of this proxy either by providing the relevant [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) or manipulating relevant [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization). More information:  [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)